# .NET Core stop HostedService in the Integration test

Tags: c#, integration-testing, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have .NET Core web API project, for some reasons, we created a background service in this project and start running the background service while the application is started.
So, we created a `BackgroundWorkderService`, which inherited from BackgroundService (Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting) like below:

```
public class BackgroundWorkerService : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await DoWork(stoppingToken);
    }

    public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

To run it while the application starts, I added the background service to the hosted service in Program.cs as below:

```
.ConfigureServices(services =>
                services.AddHostedService<BackgroundWorkerService>());
```

Now, we need to create an integration test, and we want to stop the background service while we are running the integration test.

Does anyone know how to stop it in the integration test? I have tried to remove the service from ConfigureTestServices, but no luck with it, the background service still runs when the integration test starts.

Comment: Why are you overriding `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`?

Comment: Because we'd like to have a separate service for our business logic, which will need to execute from the StartAsync

Comment: My point is that you should be able to just override `ExecuteAsync`. `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` are implemented by the `BackgroundService` type.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary, I can do it as well. But, do you have any idea how do we stop the background service from Integration test? The integration test implements the WebApplicationFactory, which will create a client, then the client starts the background service by default. This is not what we want, so how do we stop it in the Integration test?

Comment: No. You'd probably have to have some kind of external signal (like a Redis/CosmosDb lease) to prevent the background service from operating.

Comment: @StephenCleary You are quite right, I have done something like blow to disable it, hope it's helpful for someone who has the same problem with me

Comment: In program.cs file, put the host service in a conditional as below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to put the background service register in a condition as below.

Edit the Program.cs file as below in the section of registering your background service:

```
.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") != "INTEGRATION")
            {
                services.AddHostedService<BackgroundWorkerService>();
            }
        });
```

Then try to change the variable to be INTEGRATION from where you need.

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to, as you mentioned in the question, remove the service in `ConfigureTestServices`. However, exactly how we specify which service to remove is the key here.

In my experience, you need to *find* the `ServiceDescriptor` in question rather than create a new one with the expected values (see note below for why). I use LINQ and the *implementation* type of the service (in your case, `BackgroundWorkerService`) to easily find the existing `ServiceDescriptor`. Then I can remove it from the list, which means it won't be started when `CreateClient()` is called on the `WebApplicationFactory`.

Looks something like this:

```cs
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
{
    var descriptor = services.Single(s => s.ImplementationType == typeof(BackgroundWorkerService));
    services.Remove(descriptor);
}
```

A really nice benefit of this approach is that it keeps test logic out of the production code and entirely in the setup/fixture for your tests.

*Note on `IServiceCollection` removals*: With a bit of poking, I believe this is because [`ServiceDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicedescriptor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) doesn't provide an equality or comparison method other than [`Object.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0), which falls back to reference equality. So even if all the values are the same in a new `ServiceDescriptor`, they would different objects and thus won't be found and removed from the service list.

Comment: Interestingly enough there is also a `services.RemoveAll<T>` method. Unfortunately this falls short - when I have registered a service as `class BackgroundWorkerService : BackgroundService` and then call `services.RemoveAll<BackgroundWorkerService>` the service still remains...

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue so I've extended WebApplicationFactory class and removed hosted service before  by overriding CreateHost

```
    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<T> : WebApplicationFactory<T>
    where T : class
{
    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var descriptor = services.Single(s => s.ImplementationType == typeof(BackgroundService));
            services.Remove(descriptor);
        });
        return base.CreateHost(builder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are correct, but I wanted to add a little supplement as I found why `RemoveAll` could still be used.

According to the dotnet [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/Extensions/ServiceCollectionDescriptorExtensions.cs) the RemoveAll method uses `ServiceType` and not `ImplementationType` to find the service.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Removes all services of type <paramref name="serviceType"/> in <see cref="IServiceCollection"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="collection">The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/>.</param>
/// <param name="serviceType">The service type to remove.</param>
/// <returns>The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> for chaining.</returns>
public static IServiceCollection RemoveAll(this IServiceCollection collection, Type serviceType)
{
    ThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull(serviceType);

    for (int i = collection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ServiceDescriptor? descriptor = collection[i];
        if (descriptor.ServiceType == serviceType)
        {
            collection.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    return collection;
}
```

This means that we can't use actual service type of `BackgroundWorkerService` (as in the question) but instead the type it was registered with which is `IHostedService`

This means that this code can be used to nuke all background workers from existence.

```cs
services.RemoveAll<IHostedService>();
```

Unfortunately this removes also some workers that are registered by the asp.net framework, and they need to be reintroduced.